# Rewriting an Objective-C parameterless init to Swift convenience init

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, class, initialization

I have an Objective-C initializer (from another project) which I've found useful. Now I want to port it to Swift and there's a problem with Swift's naming convention.

.h

```
@interface UIViewController (FromNib)
-(nullable instancetype)initFromNib;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "FromNib.h"

@implementation UIViewController (FromNib)

-(nullable instancetype)initFromNib {

    self = [self initWithNibName: NSStringFromClass([self class])
                          bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]];

    if (self == nil) {

        NSLog(@"\nNib with name %@ not found in the main bundle.\n", NSStringFromClass([self class]));
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Since Objective-C recognizes methods which names begin with `init` it treats `init` as distinct from `initWith...` or `initFrom`.
Swift makes the distinction based on passed arguments. The only way (I have thought of) to make `init()` different from my initializer is to pass a dummy argument:

```
extension UIViewController {

    convenience init(FromNib:Int) {
        self.init()
        // the rest of the code
    }
}
```

Is there a different way to write a parameterless init in Swift, and to avoid it being confused with the designated `init()`?

Comment: Doesn't the default `UIViewController.init` doing exactly the same as your `initWithNib`? Anyway, your only workaround is to use a `class method`, e.g. `class func createFromNib() { ... }`.

Comment: Note that the dummy argument *can* be void: `convenience init(fromNib: Void)`, which would then be called as `let vc = ViewController(fromNib: ())`.

Comment: But @Sulthan is right: `let vc = MyViewController()` automatically loads the view controller from "MyViewController.nib" in the main bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sulthan and @Martin R

Good point. The default `init()` does exactly that. Thank you. Problem solved.